# Does :remote=>true in Rails3 auto downgrade?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have read about using `:remote=>true` in rails3 and know that it add `data-remote=true` attribute to the generated html tag. But `data-remote` is a new attribute introduced in html5. Will `:remote=true` auto downgrade to some compatible implementation(old js or something else) in a browser that doesn't support `data-remote` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to worry about that.

`data-remote` is not something the browsers support, but something implemented in rails-ujs (which is the jQuery-to-Rails integration lib). Pretty much all browsers today support data attributes (whey supported them even before HTML5 was introduced).

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced [custom data attributes](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#custom-data-attribute), i.e. you can add your own attributes to an element by prefixing them with `data-`. Rails uses `data-remote="true"` and adds functionality using jQuery.

Your browser just has to to be [compatible with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility).